# Best way to store, query and update 300M rows of data

Tags: redshift, dynamodb

I'm struggling to find a solution (preferably DBaaS) that I can rely on for storing and querying some 300M rows of data (roughly 100GB).

The data in question is pretty much numeric. There is also one "description" column that I would want to perform full-text search on. There are couple of "category" columns used for filtering as well. I also want to filter/order search results in many ways (10+ different indexes).

There is no need for doing complex joins since the data is pretty much denormalized. The data is updated heavily: some 50M of records are being replaced every day.

I've first tried with DynamoDB, but it can support only up to 5 indexes, and is not capable of doing full-text search at reasonable speed. I've also considered google's BigQuery, but it is designed for "append-only" data. I'm now considering Redshift, but I'm not sure how it will be able to handle such large number of daily updates.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: 300M rows/ 100GB is not huge by today's standards.  We have many DBs of this size on SQL Server, but that's a licensed product, of course.  Never versions have "updatable" columnstore indexes which may match your needs.

Comment: i agree that it is not huge, but having 50M UPDATE statements per day would pretty much crash any rdbms on single server..

Comment: Have you considered SQL Server on Azure? You can download the performance guidance whitepaper at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn248436.aspx, which should be enough to determine if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up storing data in DynamoDB and doing daily sync with Redshift. I've tried Redshift with 600M sample data on 4 node cluster and it runs extremely fast. It is exactly what i need.

Comment: I am curious, how do you handle your daily 50M record updates ? Do you do `UNLOAD` / `LOAD` queries, or directly via sql `UPDATE` or `INSERT` queries ? Or some other method ?

Comment: I'm storing records in AWS DynamoDB. It is endlessly scalable so you can perform as many updates as you want per second.